# SAP mobile platform server

Tags: mobile, sap-smp

I want to use SAP Mobile Platform.

I have got OData webservices from a SAP server.
These webservices can be consumed with SAP Mobile SDK.

DO I need to have SAP Mobile Server as well ?

What all do I need to configure in my system?

First time SAP User.

Kindly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need SMP server as well to get the benefits of SMP Mobile SDK. You have to install SMP SDK in your local development machine to start the mobile app development. You can follow [this](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-60634) how to guide.

Odata is an open standard, hence you are free to choose other free libraries to develop your native app using Odata. But for additional enterprise level features you have to use SMP SDK.

Comment: But I have questions about this.. from the point of view of a Front-end developer, What does it add? I can get the kapsel plugins to use in my app from other way...

Comment: Could you please elaborate. What is the front server you are referring to?

Answer (score 2):

SMP allows you to use:

- SAP mobile
- SDK  monitoring
- registrations of cell for  push notifications
- auto update
- Login integration
- other cordova and   kapsel plugins

also it will help to keep all your SAP servers in the intranet and only expose SMP to the wild

Configurations of SMP it´s a complex topic best option is use install guide form Service SAP (SAP user required)
http://service.sap.com/instguides

if you want to use mobile i will say it si almost mandatory. if you want to consume odata but no mobile  it´s not that necessary gateway can provide you that service